# Python - how to check if user is on the desktop

Tags: python, windows, directory, desktop

I am trying to write a program with python that works like android folders bit for Windows. I want the user to be able to single click on a desktop icon and then a window will open with the contents of the folder in it. After giving up trying to find a way to allow single click to open a desktop application (for only one application I am aware that you can allow single click for all files and folders), I decided to check if the user clicked in the location of the file and if they were on the desktop while they were doing that. So what I need to know is how to check if the user is viewing the desktop in python.

Thanks,
Harry

TLDR; how to check if user is viewing the desktop - python

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if "single clicking" would work in any way but you can use Pyautogui to automatically click as many times as you want